# java 続けますか？Y/N判定で　Nを入力しても止まりません

Tags: java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class LoToi1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //入力するための準備
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("入力された年が閏年か判別します。");
        for(;;){
        //メッセージを表示する
            System.out.println("西暦を整数入力してください。");
            try {
                //入力する情報を取得
                String line = br.readLine();
                //文字列を数値に変換
                int a = Integer.parseInt(line);
                //閏年の判定処理
                if (a%4 == 0 && a%100 != 0 || a%400 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("閏年です。");
                } else { //それ以外の処理
                    System.out.println("閏年ではありません。");
                }
                System.out.println("続けますか？Y/N");
                boolean yn = false;
                while(!yn) {
                    String input = br.readLine();
                    if(input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y")) {
                        yn=true;
                    } else if(input.equals("N") || input.equals("n")) {
                        yn=false;
　　　　　　　　　　　      break;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("YかNを入力してください。");
                    }    
                }    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //入出力時に失敗があった時に行われる処理
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(NumberFormatException e){
                //数値以外の値が入力された場合の例外処理
                System.out.println("整数で入力してください");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

else if のbreak；なぜ効かないですか？

Comment: この場合の`break` は、直近の`while`をブレイクします。`for(;;)`ではありません。 直接関係ないですが、`break`の行の前部分に全角スペースがあります。半角スペースを使うようにして下さい。

Answer (score 6):

質問の意図からすると、外側の`for()`ループを`break`で抜けようとしているのですが、直近の`while(!yn)`ループを抜けるだけになっていますね。

あまり使いませんが、ラベル付き`break`にすると解決します。

```
public class LoToi1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //入力するための準備
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("入力された年が閏年か判別します。");
        outLoop: for(;;){ // ラベルをつける
            //メッセージを表示する
            System.out.println("西暦を整数入力してください。");

            // 中略

            boolean yn = false;
            while(!yn) {
                String input = br.readLine();
                if(input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y")) {
                    yn=true;
                } else if(input.equals("N") || input.equals("n")) {
                    yn=false;
                    break outLoop; // ラベル指定でbreak
                } else {
                    System.out.println("YかNを入力してください。");
                }    
            }

            // 中略    
        } // end of for(;;)
    } // end of void main()
}
```

Comment: この回答のほうがフラグをつかうよりエレガントですね。

Comment: ･_･)そんなときには＋票を。。。w

Comment: 入れ子のループからの脱出は、GOTO文が叩かれているときの反証としてよく上がっている気がします。breakは制限付きのGOTOと言えますね。もう少し複雑な例なら例外を投げてtry-catchでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`break`を置いているのにループが継続してしまう理由としては、
この場合のbreak は、直近のwhileをブレイクするからで上層の`for`はブレイクしません。

`boolean yn` は、大本のループを継続するかどうかを表す真偽値ですから
次の様に

```
boolean yn = true;
for(;yn;){
```

`for` ループの前に置いてループの条件に使うようにします。
あるいは、

```
for(boolean yn = true; yn; ){
```

のようにします。

`while`ループは、YyNnのどれかが入力されるまでは繰り返すので、
無限ループにしてYyNnのどれかが入力されたら真偽値をynにセットしてループを抜けるようにします。

```
while(true){
    String input = br.readLine();
    if(input.equals("Y") || input.equals("y")){
        yn=true;//既定値なので必要は無い
        break;
    } else if(input.equals("N") || input.equals("n")){
        yn=false;
        break;
    }else{
        System.out.println("YかNを入力してください。");
    }
}
```

Comment: 解決できました、ありがとうございます

Comment: この回答で満足されたのであれば[承認](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)してください。